# More number of nodes in bipartite projection than node set

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm projecting a graph onto one of its node sets, but the resulting projection has more nodes than the original node set, and weirdly enough, this 'extra' nodes are just a number corresponding to a node id in G, instead of being the full (node, data) tuple.

```
C=set(n for n,d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite']==0)
len(C)
>>109813
BC=bipartite.projected_graph(G,C)
len(BC)
>>112570
len(BC)-len(C)
>>2757
```

All the 'extra' nodes at BC are just a number (corresponding to a node id in G). Where are this 'extra' 2757 nodes are coming from? I would expect a bipartite projected graph to have the same amount of nodes as the ammount of nodes in the node set it was projected onto. Any ideas?

Possible extra useful information:

```
len(G)
>>117679
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your graph is not bipartite with respect to your node set,
e.g.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: from networkx import bipartite

In [3]: G = nx.path_graph(5) # two parts, [0,2,4],[1,3]

In [4]: bipartite.projected_graph(G,[0,2,4]).nodes()
Out[4]: [0, 2, 4] # OK

In [5]: bipartite.projected_graph(G,[0,2,3]).nodes()
Out[5]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # maybe not expected or correct
```

It might be considered a bug but the documentation does warn that no bipartite check is made before doing the projection.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with the given problem. The following will not produce a bipartite graph, even though there is no error:

```
B = nx.Graph()
# Add nodes with the node attribute "bipartite"
B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from([1], bipartite=1)
# Add edges only between nodes of opposite node sets
B.add_edges_from([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)])
```

The following is the correct way to produce bipartite graph. And when you do so then bipartite projection node set will have the same nodes as the original:

```
B = nx.Graph()
# Add nodes with the node attribute "bipartite"
B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(["1"], bipartite=1)
# Add edges only between nodes of opposite node sets
B.add_edges_from([(1, "1"), (2, "1"), (3, "1"), (4, "1")])
```